# Evaluating a mathematical expression stored as a string, into a single number (bash)

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am working on Mac OSX and using bash as my shell. I currently have a string which I wish want evaluated as a number. When I echo the string I get `1.e8*1.07**100`. Is there any way to pass this string on to be evaluated as a number?

The background as to why it is a string to start with is because the expression was built step by step. First `1.e8*1.07**%%d` is within the code, then the user inputs an integer to be taken as what 1.07 will be raised to the power of. So in the example above, the user would have input 100, and thus the script is stuck with `1.e8*1.07**100`, which is the correct expression I was hoping for, but I would have liked it to be evaluated when I echo the variable where it is store.

Actual important bits of code:

```
BASE=$(printf '1.e8*1.07**%%d')
#Get user input assigned to pow
NUM=$(printf ${BASE} ${pow})
echo $NUM       #1.e8*1.07**100
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

[Edit: I would also like to not just echo the answer, but store it as a variable.]

Comment: It depends on how your arithmetic syntax is defined. bash has an arithmetic language built in; bc has a different one; Python has a different one; etc. So, are you writing Python expressions? dc expressions? Matlab expressions?

Comment: you should get a look at : `man bc` . ex: `echo "1 + 2" | bc`

Comment: @rici: What is the "it"? There are dozens of arithmetic expression languages, and I mentioned at least 5 in my comment.

Comment: @abarnert: You edited the comment after I replied, so you should know perfectly well what I was referring to.

Comment: @rici: The original version mentioned bash, Python, and C. So, that's 3, not 5. And the point is unchanged from the original version: you can't just "evaluate arithmetic expressions". You can evaluate Python arithmetic expressions, or dc arithmetic expressions, or bash arithmetic expressions, etc., but you have to know which one you're doing before you can do the right one.

Comment: @abarnert what I remember seeing only mentioned bash, but maybe I misread. If so, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
python -c "print $NUM"
```

By the way, you could just write

```
BASE="1.e8*1.07**%d"
```

(In fact, you don't even need the quotes.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm an inexperienced coder. How would you ago about also assigning that to a variable. (I've never used python)

Comment: @NoviceC The same way you do the other ones. `EVAL=$(python -c "print $NUM")`

Comment: wow thanks, worked like a charm. Also thanks for cleaning up my code.

Answer (score 2):

In most unix* systems you'll find a tool called `bc` that can perform calculations. You'll might need to rewrite your input though, I thinks it accepts `^` instead of `**`, and I'm not sure about the `1.e8` notation.

Comment: Or pipe it through sed `echo 1.e8*1.07**100 | sed 's/e/\*10\^/' | sed 's/\*\*/\^/' |sed 's/+//' | bc -q` for example.

Comment: @TimothyBrown, you don't need 3 separate sed commands, use the `-e` option. Also use `bc -l` which gives extra precision: `echo '1.e8*1.07**100' | sed -e 's/e/*10^/g' -e 's/\*\*/^/g' | bc -l`

Answer (score 2):

It  happens that perl can evaluate that exact expression

```
$ x="1.e8*1.07**100"
$ y=$(perl -E "say $x")
$ echo $y
86771632556.6417
```